# InstanceOnPoints: how to parametrize the instances depending on the points (Blender 3.0)

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances

in the example below, the Strings should show any specific value of the curve points. For example the index+1 esp. the hours of a clock, or any other attribute.

How can I grab values from the curve points and use them as parameter for the StringToCurves instance template.

[image]

I also tried to use a GroupInput with a cube, but with no success.

[image]

Is it even possible that way or is the StringToCurves constant before instantiating.
How can I realize the clock in the example in a generic way?

Many thanks for hints or a solution...

---

for now, I found a workaround based on Chris answer (picking from collection).
Made a collection with 10 digits (0..9) and picked the digits by index from the collection. The indices can be computed from points attributes.

[image]

Comment: an instance of "instance on points" can only be changed by rotation and scale on an per instance basis. That's why there is this this "rhombus" sign on the instance on points node. The filled circles mean: this are "one time" values. So you cannot change it on an per instance basis. AFAIK at the current state of GN you cannot solve this "easy" as you thought. But...you could make a collection of 12 texts...then it works

Comment: if you are open to animation nodes - > there this is already possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this node setup (but i don't think it is easier at this moment of the GN development):

[image]

So i made a collection of 12 texts and put it in a collection.

---

With animation nodes you can make your numbers with 5 nodes only!!

[image]

result:

[image]

---

Here a setup, how you can make the whole watch in AN (might be not the easiest solution, but it works):

[image]

Hint: you should hide the target in the outliner

Comment: thank you Chris, the hint with picking an instance from collection by index was helpful for me to find this workaround:

If it is possible to pick elements from a set of elements,
then I could pick the digits of a number (0...9) depending on the points Index and combine them to a number.

AnimationNodes looks interesting but seem not to availabble for Blender 3.0 yet.

Comment: animation nodes is a free amazing (!) add-on which you can download ;) https://animation-nodes.com/#download or on github

Comment: if my answer helped you, please click on the checkmark left of my answer. Thank you.

Comment: did it, thanks. Short question. How can I acces the index from an Object, that is created in the GeoNodes Graph itself (not passed in)

Comment: there is an index node for that

Comment: but maybe i misunderstood you. can u tell me, what your "end goal" is? what do you want to achieve?

Comment: that seems only to work for Objects passed in via GroupInput.

Comment: i would suggest you open a new question with screenshot...it is difficult just by comments to understand what you want now...

Comment: ups sorry, works also with an internal CurveCircle. Currently I don't understand why it works, because there could be more than one Objects, but only one Index node.

Comment: the index node (as many other nodes) are corresponding to that node which they are plugged in to. So also it is the same node, the contents is often different. e.g. [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyvaS.jpg you see that? same index node, but totally different content if you look at the spreadsheet. The captured index is the index 0 and 1 from the mesh line, and the "normal" index is from the box (8 vertices) multiplied by 2 vertices (from the mesh line), so it goes from 0 to 15.

Comment: I see, btw. AnimationNodes works in Blender 3 - very useful. Many thanks!

Comment: you are welcome